# compile tensorrt sample not found NvOnnxParserTypedefs.h

Tags: tensorrt, onnx

i have install tensorrt
i have already checked python -c "import tensorrt"

but when i compile tensorrt sample

```
make
```

it throws out

../../include/NvOnnxParser.h:27:10: **fatal error**: NvOnnxParserTypedefs.h: No such file or directory
 #include "NvOnnxParserTypedefs.h"

i find include file in the dictionary

```
ls ../../include
```

the result is

```
NvCaffeParser.h  NvInferPlugin.h  NvOnnxParser.h         NvUffParser.h
NvInfer.h        NvOnnxConfig.h   NvOnnxParserRuntime.h  NvUtils.h
```

who can help me？
there maybe some useful resources 
https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/blob/release/6.0/samples/opensource/sampleMNIST/README.md
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-sample-support-guide/index.html#mnist_sample
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-install-guide/index.html#installing-tar
https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/tree/release/5.1
https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorrt/tree/5.1
https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/blob/release/6.0/samples/opensource/sampleMNIST/README.md

Answer (score 1):

i fixed this issues

may be your compiler not found the NvOnnxParserTypedefs.h file 
try

```
sudo find / -name NvOnnxParserTypedefs.h
```

and do the follow script

```
sudo cp /your/path/to/NvOnnxParserTypedefs.h /your_tensorrt_path/include/
```

and it may work

Comment: Indeed, that bug is mentioned here but so far nothing https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorrt/issues/193